# How do I make iTerm terminal notify me when a job/process is complete?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, iterm2

A notification center notification would be ideal but growl, bounce dock, sound, etc would be fine, too (or if this can only be done in Terminal.app I'd be willing to switch back). Is there an option somewhere in iTerm to turn on notifications or is it something I'm supposed to type at the end of a command in the terminal? If the latter, is it possible to add an alert once process has started (for example if I realize it's going to take longer than I initially expected, I'm bad at guessing).

Answer (score 345):

## Notify on an already running process:

- Go to `Edit` → `Marks and Annotations` → `Alerts` → `Alert on next mark`
- or use Shortcut: <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

**`iTerm`** will literally keep an eye of your terminal ([image: Spooky eye!], on the top right corner).
Once the command is finished, it will issue a notification.

---

##### Requirement: [Shell Integration:](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html)

- `iTerm2` → `Install Shell Integration`
- **NOTE**: integration will not issue notifications until iTerm2 is **restarted**.

---

##### Use Case:

We launched a command, underestimated completion time, and we don't want to cancel or just wait for completion.

Comment: After installing shell integrations you might want to go to iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal , scroll down & uncheck "Show mark indicators", I did not like this shell integration.  You might also want to Edit -> Marks and Annotations -> Alerts -> Post notification if you want the os notifications instead of an alert style popup.

Comment: @simonhamp I suggest using triggers (https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html) for buried sessions

Comment: @dwanderson Did you ever get this working with tmux? This would be so helpful

Comment: @Lucas there is a line in the docs that says that shell integration doesn't work with tmux or screen https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html

Comment: This eye scares me!! (╯‵□′)╯︵┻━┻

Comment: The alert does not work on ssh sessions for me. Anyone experience the same?

Comment: @ShamalKarunarathne Have you installed the shell integration scripts in the machines you are SSHing to?

Comment: @GregL Thank you it worked. Didn't know I had to install the integration in SSH hosts as well.

Comment: This is working well in my case, not sure how to turn it on for all the commands I run with iTerm2, here, I have to enable it for each & every command I fire.

Answer (score 94):

And you can always use the `say` command.

Usually when you are running a long process inside the terminal and want to get updated you can simply use this command to speak out things like `done` or `error` or `bazinga`.

```
mvn clean install; say done
```

This command builds a java spring app, and takes a long long time, and it will speak out `done` after the process is complete.

Comment: OMG not only this is helpful, but so cool and a very straightforward way to do it.

Comment: This answer is not receiving enough votes given its awesomeness. 

Comment: THIS IS SIMPLE YET AMAZING!

Comment: This is super awesome! How didnt I know it ???

Answer (score 68):

You can add any one of the following after any command, with a semi-colon in between the command and it:

```
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff -v 2

osascript -e 'beep 3'

tput bel
```

or, if you like Notification Centre

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'
```

You can also make an alias in your profile, called `notify` and add that at the end of your command. So, in your login profile

```
alias notify="tput bel"
```

then

```
sleep 10; notify
```

Or, if you started your command and it is "hanging", just type `notify` and hit `Enter` and it will run your `notify` alias at the end, when the command has finished, e.g.

```
sleep 20

# wait 5 seconds before realising this will take 20 seconds
notify<Enter>
```

Comment: Hmm, with this command `osascript -e 'display notification "Task finished" with title "Terminal"'` I seem to be getting this error `2015-05-04 12:34:23.227 osascript[30467:1130887] Error loading /Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax/Contents/MacOS/List & Record Tools:  dlopen(/Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax/Contents/MacOS/List & Record Tools, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:`

Comment: part two of error `/Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax/Contents/MacOS/List & Record Tools: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax" declares no loadable handlers.`

Comment: Are you on a system older than Mavericks or Yosemite?

Comment: Nope, Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: Oh, that's odd. Can you try something simpler like `osascript -e 'display notification "Hello"'` - by specifically copying and pasting from here.

Comment: Result:    (testenv3)testenv3 > osascript -e 'display notification "Hello"'
2015-05-04 19:56:53.205 osascript[57251:2660824] Error loading /Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax/Contents/MacOS/List & Record Tools:  dlopen(/Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax/Contents/MacOS/List & Record Tools, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax/Contents/MacOS/List & Record Tools: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

Comment: part two:     osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Users/mmarotta/Library/ScriptingAdditions/List & Record Tools.osax" declares no loadable handlers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell this is great!! Is there a way to not open apple script editor when I click on the notification by accident?

Comment: `tput bel` is great because it also works when connected to another machine via e.g. ssh.

Comment: to chain osascript notification and beep: `alias notify="osascript -e 'display notification \"execution finished\"'; osascript -e 'beep 5'"`

Answer (score 22):

`iTerm2` supports `Growl` notifications. You can turn it on in each profile settings.

Select a profile in `Preferences…`->`Profiles`.
Then in `Terminal` tab there is an option `Enable Growl Notifications`.

Remember to also enable `iTerm` notifications in `Growl` preferences.

If you want to get notification for a given process you could try to experiment with `Triggers`. You define triggers in `Advanced` tab in a profile settings. In this way you may assign a Growl notification to a particular output of your process (regexp).

You could for example do:

```
$ mycommand; echo "end-of-my-process"
```

And connect trigger to "end-of-my-process" message.

**Update**

Read more about triggers on [iTerm2.com](https://iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html).

Comment: So am I correct that there is no global way to get an alert for any finished process because I need to have run the script once to know what it writes at the end of the process (and I have to create one for every script I run)? For example, the last line for a youtube-dl process is `[download] 100% of 40.13MiB in 00:13` but this line is repeated for every file it finishes. What would I put in for my 'end-of-my-process' string? Could I make a trigger for when my default shell prompt `~ >` shows up again?

Comment: @truth1ness I don't think there is a generic way to be informed about finished process. `iTerm` sends notifications for new terminal output, for end of terminal output. This can work for some processes. The way to work for all processes is what I suggested. "end-of-my-process" message can be any unique string. Unique it such way that it will not be printed by your process. Could be literally "end-of-my-process" text. You must enter exactly same string in the trigger definition and attach a notification to it. I don't know if it will work with shell prompt. You must try it yourself.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I got it now. I was able to get an alert to pop up with the echo output "end-of-my-process". However, I also get an alert when I actually issue the echo command before the process starts. How would I tell iTerm to ignore the string when I actually issue the command and only look at the echo'd string? From the help file I tried prepending the trigger regex with \0 ("The entire value matched by the regular expression.") but it still executes the trigger twice.

Comment: @truth1ness Be creative, for example use `echo "end-of-""my-process"`  with quotes inside. It will match "end-of-my-process" text only when process finished.

Answer (score 12):

There is an OSS tool called [noti](https://github.com/variadico/noti).

You can easily install it with `brew install noti` and start using it just by prefixing your command with `noti` like `noti sleep 3`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `terminal-notifier` which use mac os system notifications. To install it via Home brew just:

```
$ brew install terminal-notifier
```

Then if you want to display notification when your job/process is done use something like this

```
$ <your job/process command> && echo 'Completed' | terminal-notifier -sound default
```

And this display like this:

[image]

You can also change sound and icon of notifications. More info in github repo: https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier

Answer (score 7):

Install the iTerm2 shell integration

```sh
curl -L https://iterm2.com/shell_integration/install_shell_integration_and_utilities.sh | bash
```

Execute your command and concatenate the attention app, e.g.

```
./task && ~/.iterm2/it2attention once
```

It'll cause the iTerm app to bounce it's icon once the job is complete.

You also have other attention options:

```
$ .iterm2/it2attention -h
Usage:
  it2attention start
    Begin bouncing the dock icon if another app is active
  it2attention stop
    Stop bouncing the dock icon if another app is active
  it2attention once
    Bounce the dock icon once if another app is active
  it2attention fireworks
    Show an explosion animation at the cursor
```