# iTerm: set marks in SSH session

Tags: bash, iterm2, iterm

I'm trying to make iTerm give me a notification whenever a command I run in an SSH session completes. To do this, I [set marks](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) whenever I run a command which notifies me whenever the command completes. However, it seems like I can't set when I am ssh'd into a server—the eye appears, but nothing happens when the command has been completed. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Install [shell integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) on the remote machine, and adding `iterm2_prompt_mark` to the `PS1` of the remote machine will do the trick.

To use the feature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41667800/13109740