# How To Play A Beep/Alert Sound On Mac In Java

Tags: java

I have tried using both

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();` and

`System.out.println("\007");`

and neither are actually playing a sound. I tried running the code in my IDE (CodeRunner 2) and in Terminal to see if it made a difference, which it didn't.

If anyone know another way to do this or why it isn't working, please let me know

Thanks!

Comment: Do you hear sound at all when you type `tput bel` or [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127977/3429133) in your terminal?

Comment: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();` works for me. Are you sure everything else is as it should be? Did you try beatngu's suggestion (which also played the System beep on my machine)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

works for me while following does not work (MacOS Sonoma 14.1)

```
executeCommand("tput bel");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for [`Runtime#exec(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

This should allow you to get an instance of the current environment in which you can issue such commands.

Comment: Thanks you all though this isn't exactly working, could you show some of the formalities?

Comment: Been trying it myself right now and can't get the damn thing to beep XD, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); does seem to work for me though

Comment: My brother just came to the rescue. getRuntime is a method. You wrote it here without the brackets.

Comment: Yeah i'm seeing that myself right now... stupid mistake! Still i do wonder why the Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); doesn't work for you

Comment: @a-sir Next time: if you're seeing a mistake you made, please fix it by editing your post.

Answer (score -1):

Or you might try to use it with JNA-Library:

```
   import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
   import com.sun.jna.Native;
   import com.sun.jna.Library;

   interface JnaTests extends Library {
    public boolean Beep(int FREQUENCY , int DURATION );
    static Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class); 
   static void startBeep() throws InterruptedException { 
   kernel32.Beep(1200, (5000)); 
   Thread.sleep(50); 
  }
```

}

---

```
  package com.sun.jna.platform;


  import com.sun.jna.Library;

   public class win32 {

   private static class MSG implements User32 {

    public MSG() {
    }
   }

  public interface Kernel32 extends Library { // ... (lines deleted for   clarity) ...  
    boolean Beep(int frequency, int duration); 
     //int GetLogicalDrives(); // ... (lines deleted for clarity)   ...      }   
    }
   public interface User32 extends Library { // ... (lines deleted for  clarity) ...  
        // ... (lines deleted for clarity) ... }
   }
  }
```

---

```
  Perhaps you could use the midi class too:



Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.open();
Sequence sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
Track track = sequence.createTrack();
ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
a.setMessage(144,9,56,100);
MidiEvent event = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
track.add(event);
sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
sequencer.start();
Thread.sleep(500);
sequencer.close();
```

Comment: I don't think any Mac user is going to have Kernel32 on their system...

Comment: This answer lacks proper explanation (and formatting).